# SQL JOIN to two separate Child Tables without crossing them

Tags: sql

I have a parent table with two separate children:

Parent

```
ID  Name
1   One
2   Two
```

Child 1:

```
Par_ID Key Name
1      1   Apple
1      2   Orange
2      1   Pear
```

Child 2:

```
Par_ID Key Name
1      1   Red
2      1   Blue
2      2   Green
```

When I do a LEFT JOIN on each, it basically does a cross join on the two children.

What I'm trying to get is the following:

```
Parent_ID   Child1_Name   Child2_Name
1           Apple         Red
1           Orange        NULL
2           Pear          Blue
2           NULL          Green
```

Comment: You are probably looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Since some of them does not support `FULL JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a full join based on both keys:

```
select *
from [Child 1] c1
full join [Child 2] c2 on c1.Par_ID=c2.Par_ID and c1.key=c2.key
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` with the correct conditions:

```
select p.id, c1.name, c2.name
from parent p left join
     child1 c1
     on c1.par_id = c1.id left join
     child2 c2
     on c2.par_id = c2.id and c2.key = c1.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` if your DBMS supports such as

```
SELECT COALESCE(c1.Par_ID,c2.Par_ID) AS Parent_ID, c1.Name AS Child1_Name, c2.Name AS Child2_Name
  FROM Parent p
  FULL JOIN Child1 c1
    ON c1.Par_ID = p.ID   
  FULL JOIN Child2 c2
    ON c2.Par_ID = p.ID
   AND c2.Key = c1.Key
```

Otherwise, you can use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` in such a way that

```
SELECT Parent_ID, MAX(Child1_Name) AS Child1_Name, MAX(Child2_Name) AS Child2_Name
  FROM 
  (   
    SELECT c1.Key,c1.Par_ID AS Parent_ID,c1.Name AS Child1_Name,NULL AS Child2_Name 
      FROM Parent p
      LEFT JOIN Child1 c1
        ON c1.Par_ID = p.ID   
     UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.Key,c2.Par_ID,NULL,c2.Name 
      FROM Parent p
      LEFT JOIN Child2 c2
        ON c2.Par_ID = p.ID   
  ) cc  
 GROUP BY key, Parent_ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nsFVkKaC4APvobrTpqQ3in/0)</kbd>